# split a column into N groups by value differences (timestamp)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Sample data in .csv format

```
| No.|   IP     |      Unix_time     |    # integer unix time
| 1  | 1.1.1.1  |     1563552000     |    # equivalent to 12:00:00 AM
| 2  | 1.1.1.1  |     1563552030     |    # equivalent to 12:00:30 AM
| 3  | 1.1.1.1  |     1563552100     |    # equivalent to 12:01:40 AM
| 4  | 1.1.1.1  |     1563552110     |    # equivalent to 12:01:50 AM
| 5  | 1.1.1.1  |     1563552180     |    # equivalent to 12:03:00 AM
| 6  | 1.2.3.10 |     1563552120     |
```

Here's the current working code using *pandas* **groupby( )** and **get_group( )** functions:

```
data = pd.read_csv(some_path, header=0)
root = data.groupby('IP')

for a in root.groups.keys():
    t = root.get_group(a)['Unix_time']
    print(a + 'has' + t.count() + 'record')
```

You will see the results below:

```
1.1.1.1 has 5 record
1.2.3.10 has 1 record
```

Now, I want some improvement based on above code.

For the same **IP** value (e.g., 1.1.1.1), I want to make further **sub-groups** based on a maximum time interval (e.g., 60 seconds), and **count the number of elements in each sub-group**. For example, in above sample data:

Start from row 1: row 2 Unix_time value is within 60 seconds, but row 3 is beyond 60 seconds.

Thus, **row 1-2 is a group, row 3-4 is a separate group, row 5 is a separate group**. In other words, group '1.1.1.1' has 3 sub-groups now. The result should be:

```
1.1.1.1 start time 1563552000 has 2 record within 60 secs
1.1.1.1 start time 1563552100 has 2 record within 60 secs
1.1.1.1 start time 1563552150 has 1 record within 60 secs
1.2.3.10 start time 1563552120 has 1 record within 60 secs
```

How to make it?

Comment: It seems to me like row 5 should be grouped with rows 3 and 4 according to the rules you are describing since rows 3, 4, and 5 all occur within the 100 second window starting at 1563552100. What have I misunderstood?

Comment: @moormanly: yes, i make a mistake. i make revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.Grouper`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Unix_time'], unit='s')
for n, g in df.groupby(['IP', pd.Grouper(freq='60s', key='datetime')]):
    print(f'{n[0]} start time {g.iloc[0, g.columns.get_loc("Unix_time")]} has {len(g)} records within 60 secs')
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1  start time 1563552000 has 2 records within 60 secs
1.1.1.1  start time 1563552100 has 2 records within 60 secs
1.1.1.1  start time 1563552150 has 1 records within 60 secs
1.2.3.10 start time 1563552120 has 1 records within 60 secs
```

---

### Using "root" and integers:

```
root = df.groupby(['IP',df['Unix_time']//60])

for n, g in root:
     print(f'{n[0]} start time {g.iloc[0, g.columns.get_loc("Unix_time")]} has {len(g)} records within 60 secs')
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1  start time 1563552000 has 2 records within 60 secs
1.1.1.1  start time 1563552100 has 2 records within 60 secs
1.1.1.1  start time 1563552150 has 1 records within 60 secs
1.2.3.10 start time 1563552120 has 1 records within 60 secs
```

Comment: in my case, df is root.get_group(a)?

Comment: is it possible not use to_datetime? if i just want to read them as integers

Comment: it works for my sample data only. But if the time are e.g., 1563557387 and 1563557418. they are within 60 seconds, but their // 60 values (26059289 & 26059290) are different, so don not fall in the same group

Comment: Yeah it is better to convert to datetime

Comment: i tested the datetime method, it always starts to count from :00 second of the minute, instead of the real start time of each group.