# Incorrect number of records within a group when using df,groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have following modified code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57518649/7356355) to split rows into 5 seconds groups based on timestamp.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter=',')
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], unit='s')
for g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5s', key='dt')):
    print(f'Start time {g[0]} has {len(g)} records within 5 secs')
```

but I am getting incorrect number of records within the group.

Output

```
Start time 2017-05-02 16:00:45 has 2 records within 5 secs
...
```

Sample CSV would look like below

```
datetime,x,y,z,label
1493740845,0.0004,-0.0001,0.0045,bad
1493740846,0.0004,0.0006,0.0049,bad
1493740847,0.0002,0.0013,0.0044,bad
1493740848,0.0002,0.0005,0.0046,bad
1493740849,0.0006,0.0006,0.0038,bad
1493740850,0.0009,0.0002,0.0038,bad
...
```

Comment: @jezrael I added output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `g` tuple with 2 values, so always get `2`.

I think you can unpack tuple to `name` and `g` variables, so then working like you need:

```
for name, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5s', key='dt')):
    print(f'Start time {name} has {len(g)} records within 5 secs')

Start time 2017-05-02 16:00:45 has 5 records within 5 secs
Start time 2017-05-02 16:00:50 has 1 records within 5 secs
```

In your solution use `g[1]` for `length`s:

```
for g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5s', key='dt')):
    print(f'Start time {g[0]} has {len(g[1])} records within 5 secs')
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works. I like your profile philosophy about reasoning about downvoting. I share the same

Comment: @user158 - hmmm, in reality it should be better, but nowadays I think the less downvotes is better like more I realised ;) It should be used carefully, mainly for answers.

Comment: I think you are saying about new answers using newer APIs? If so that can be fixed by sorting answer by active.

Comment: @user158 - I think generally, but there I before flaging first try understand why was posted same answer;)

Comment: Yah duplicated answers are annoying, reason for this is people trying to exploit answer sorting settings. If reader answer sort settings is set to active most recent answers will be on the top, which resulting in more upvotes from new readers.

Comment: I need a little help!. It seems you know the `pandas` API well, may I ask how you learned the it? is it through experience? course or etc. I am new to data side. I am glad to know any helpful resources or tips to learn pandas API?

Comment: @user158 - Sure, but I have no magic here. For me working coding, many rows of codes with learn from another people in SO. So for me it was really long process. But if you have experience with `R` or matlab or similar, you can understand principe of data processing, so easier search in SO. There is a lot problems solved, only find it is not so easy.